# How to create a AMP video viewer counter?

Tags: amp-html

in [AMP](https://www.ampproject.org/) we can analytic videos, For example, we write this code for analyzing video performance.

```
"triggers": {
  "myVideoPlay": {
    "on": "video-play",
    "request": "event",
    "selector": "#myVideo",
    "videoSpec": {/* optional videoSpec */}
  },
}
```

can we use this `trigger` for *Video Viewer Counter*?